# How to stop a fragment from resetting every time I change tabs

Tags: java, android

I was just wondering how I could prevent my tab from resetting every time I switch to another? I've created a 4 tab bottom menu, and every time I switch, they reload. I'm still relatively new to coding in Java, so I'm a bit lost.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    private WebView webView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
//

        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.it");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
        webSettings.supportZoom();
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true
        );


        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate()` of the fragments, call `setRetainInstance(true)`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)

If your number of tabs is fixed then you can also try:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);
```

limit = number of pages to retain

Comment: `public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        setRetainInstance(true);` I tried it like this, but it still refreshes each time.

Comment: Updated the answer, if your number of tabs is fixed :)

Comment: mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);
this should help